# C variables overwriting values

Tags: c, pointers

Hi I implemented a linked list and I am having troubles updating the variables of the struc Process i created. Here is the sample code:

```
typedef struct Process {
    int pid;
    char name[256];
    int prior;    
    int state;
    int start_time;   
} Process;

typedef struct Node {
    Process *value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;


Node *create_node(){
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));
    temp->value = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void append(Node *head, Node *nodo){
    Node *current = head;
    while (current->next != NULL){
        current = current->next;
    }    
    current->next = nodo;
}



void add_attr(char *string, Process *procc){    
    char *pch;
    pch = strtok(string, " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        if (i == 0){
            strcpy(procc->name,pch);              
        }
        else if(i == 1){           
            int aux = atoi(pch);            
            procc->prior = aux;                                 
        }
        else{            
            int aux1 = atoi(pch);
            procc->start_time = aux1;                
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }


int main(int argc, char * argv []) {    
    FILE *fp;
    int pid = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    fp = fopen(argv[1],"r");
    Node *process_list = create_node();    
    Process *proc = malloc(sizeof(Process));
    proc->pid = pid;
    proc->state = 0;
    process_list->value = proc;
    pid += 1 ;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("%s\n",line);        
        add_attr(line, proc);
        printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("pointer proc memory dir = %p\n", proc);
        printf("pid = %d\n",proc->pid);
        printf("name = %s\n",proc->name);
        printf("pior = %d\n",proc->prior);
        printf("state = %d\n",proc->state);
        printf("start_time = %d\n",proc->start_time);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n");
        Node *nodo = create_node();
        Process *proc = malloc(sizeof(Process));
        proc->pid = pid;       
        proc->state = 0;
        nodo->value = proc;
        append(process_list, nodo); 
        pid = pid +1;
    }    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

There is the main()
as you can see i printed the state of the variables in the struct to see their values and all goes well except for the pid that is not changing. after the while loop finished i printed all the processes in my linked list and its attributes and they all changed. Here you can see a SS with the output.
[image]

I really don't know what is happening to my program any help would be great, i know its a very specific case, but i did not know how to make a working example that showed the same problem.
(*I updated the output now the pid's work, but the main issue is not fixed, i still can't figure out why the Process attr change).

```
Input sample:
p1 2 3 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 8 9
p2 1 4 8 6 2 6 4 3 2 2 1
p3 3 5 5 1 2 6 7 8
```

Comment: `pid = pid++` is invalid. It should be either `pid++` or `pid = pid + 1`

Comment: Post the code as text, not an image.

Comment: `Process *proc = malloc(sizeof(Process)); proc->pid++;`. Given that `proc->pid` is unassigned, you attempt to increase a random value (it's probably 0, but could be anything, as this is afaik undefined behaviour). You probably want `proc->pid = pid++;`

Comment: @Evert it worked thanks, but i still have the problem of the values of the nodes of my linked list change at the end

Comment: did u try stepping though your code with a debugger?

Comment: @pm100 no I don't haven't tried one (don't know one that is good and easy to use) I tried doing a lot of prints but i still can't figure it out

Comment: your toolchain (you dont say what you are using) should include a debugger. If not, get another toolchain. On linux use gdb.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, `pid = pid++;` is undefined behavior.

Use `pid = pid + 1`, `pid++`, or `pid += 1` instead

---

**UPDATE:**

You were setting `proc->pid` *after* printing, so it would print as zero. Actually, what it printed was what `malloc` returned, so it could have been anything and just happened to be zero most of the time.

But, you also have another problem. You append a new node in the bottom of the loop in anticipation of reading the node's contents on the *next* loop iteration.

So, because you appended "one ahead", the resultant linked list will have one too many nodes, and the last node will have garbage data. You don't see this in the loop itself, but *would* during *subsequent* list traversal [and printing].

I've created two versions of your program. One with the bugs annotated. And a cleaned up version.

Here's the annotated version [which prints correctly]:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Process {
    int pid;
    char name[256];
    int prior;
    int state;
    int start_time;
} Process;

typedef struct Node {
    Process *value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *
create_node()
{
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    temp->value = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void
append(Node * head, Node * nodo)
{
    Node *current = head;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = nodo;
}

void
add_attr(char *string, Process * procc)
{
    char *pch;

    pch = strtok(string, " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            strcpy(procc->name, pch);
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            int aux = atoi(pch);

            procc->prior = aux;
        }
        else {
            int aux1 = atoi(pch);

            procc->start_time = aux1;
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int pid = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    Node *process_list = create_node();
    Process *proc = malloc(sizeof(Process));

    proc->pid = pid;
    proc->state = 0;
    process_list->value = proc;
    pid += 1;
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("%s\n", line);
        add_attr(line, proc);

// NOTE/FIX: this is the correct place to set the pid -- _before_ printing
#if 0
        proc->pid = pid;
#endif

        printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("pointer proc memory dir = %p\n", proc);
        printf("pid = %d\n", proc->pid);
        printf("name = %s\n", proc->name);
        printf("pior = %d\n", proc->prior);
        printf("state = %d\n", proc->state);
        printf("start_time = %d\n", proc->start_time);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n");

// NOTE/BUG: this is setting up the _next_ node before it is known if it will
// be filled
        Node *nodo = create_node();
        Process *proc = malloc(sizeof(Process));

// NOTE/BUG: this is set _after_ the printing is done
#if 1
        proc->pid = pid;
#endif

// NOTE/BUG: this is appending the node before it is filled in (i.e. the last
// node in the list will have garbage)
        proc->state = 0;
        nodo->value = proc;
        append(process_list, nodo);

        pid = pid + 1;
    }

    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

---

Here's the cleaned up and working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Process {
    int pid;
    char name[256];
    int prior;
    int state;
    int start_time;
} Process;

typedef struct Node {
    Process *value;
    struct Node *next;
} Node;

Node *
create_node()
{
    Node *temp = malloc(sizeof(Node));

    temp->value = NULL;
    temp->next = NULL;
    return temp;
}

void
append(Node * head, Node * nodo)
{
    Node *current = head;

    while (current->next != NULL) {
        current = current->next;
    }
    current->next = nodo;
}

void
add_attr(char *string, Process * procc)
{
    char *pch;

    pch = strtok(string, " ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
            strcpy(procc->name, pch);
        }
        else if (i == 1) {
            int aux = atoi(pch);

            procc->prior = aux;
        }
        else {
            int aux1 = atoi(pch);

            procc->start_time = aux1;
        }
        pch = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fp;
    int pid = 0;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    Node *process_list = create_node();
    Process *proc = malloc(sizeof(Process));

    proc->pid = pid;
    proc->state = 0;
    process_list->value = proc;

    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("%s\n", line);

        Process *proc = malloc(sizeof(Process));
        add_attr(line, proc);
        proc->state = 0;

        pid += 1;
        proc->pid = pid;

        Node *nodo = create_node();
        nodo->value = proc;
        append(process_list, nodo);

        printf("---------------------------------------------------------\n");
        printf("pointer proc memory dir = %p\n", proc);
        printf("pid = %d\n", proc->pid);
        printf("name = %s\n", proc->name);
        printf("pior = %d\n", proc->prior);
        printf("state = %d\n", proc->state);
        printf("start_time = %d\n", proc->start_time);
        printf("----------------------------------------------------------\n");
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: sorry my bad it was an older version, but i fixed and it didn't work either.

Comment: I'd love to know why this answer got DV'ed, particularly after getting +2

Comment: because it didn't help, it was my bad uploading and older version but if you want i can delete these post and upload it again with the right version, i don't see why an answer that didnt help at all should get a vote

Comment: Downvoting is reserved for a _substantially_ bad answer. The answer doesn't have to be complete. And, the answer was _correct_, based on your original post. Your post was also incomplete because it reads from a file, but you didn't post [some of] your input data. So, there was no way to test any solution. And, no, do _not_ delete this post [and repost]. That is frowned upon. Just edit your post to improve it. Often, posts and answers are edited in multiple rounds, until a solution is found. Think of it as a collaboration between poster and responder

Comment: @M.M The answer was as complete as could be provided at the time [without having to synthesize OP's input data for testing]. Now that OP [per my request] posted his data, I was able to diagnose/fix his bug, and also find/fix a second one he didn't see